# Spring boot admin client and server inside the same application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing a spring boot webapp and now I need to manage it with spring boot admin. By creating another spring webapp and make it the admin server, everything works just fine, but now I need to implement server and client on the same webapp. How can I do that?

On my webapp i'v added this on my application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=Events generator
spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8080
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
server.port=8081
```

What I need to do to make this webapp either client and server for Spring boot admin?

Comment: I am trying the same thing, but get the following error. So I am not sure if it is possible to have an admin client and server in the same application. Did you manage to get it to work? `Failed to register application as Application(...): 401 : [no body].`

Comment: Also, i think your ports should be the same on the following properties: `spring.boot.admin.client.url` and `server.port`.